# getting print numeric value 6 on every page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I am using PHP codeigniter & codeigniter-restserver.
I am getting numaric value 6 all pages. Even if I check default codeigniter welcome page. I am getting 6 on top of page. 
I scanned entire file system for numaric value 6. I am not able to find logical or typo mistake.

Is this 6 is some kind of error msg code? 
I change error code in constants.php just to rule out this file.
Any hint .. will be helpful. 
*Surprise part is, on local Machine I am not getting this problem. its only on Web hosting.*

[image]
[image]

**View - welcome_message.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
    }

    a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

    #body {
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }

    p.footer {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #container {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">
        <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

        <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
        <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

        <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
        <code>application/controllers/Welcome.php</code>

        <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Might be `echo`ed or accidently typed in your common view file either header/footer

Comment: can you show the controller and view file (header, footer) etc?

Comment: I added few screenshot above. I checked I am not doing any echo.

Comment: Yea could be in the header file, can you please show us all the views, you have.

Comment: @Farhana : how I can show header file to you ?

Comment: @fresher Add header file content in question.

Comment: @fresher there is a folder called views, all the files there, can you post all those codes?

Comment: I haven't created any header file or views, my own everything is default. I written an Api which return JSON object. My front end is totally separate. I am using PHP for REST calls only

Comment: @fresher but there is a view called welcome message, I am pretty sure of it

Comment: @Farhana - Code added above

Comment: @fresher okay its not there, how about you do something, like search the whole codeigniter folder for a 6, if you are using IDE it will be easy

Comment: @fresher when you right click the 6, and inspect, what does it show ?

Comment: check your controller or model did you use echo or print before loading a veiw?

2. Any header files if you have added

Comment: @Farhana I added screen of inspect. I already scan all file system with value 6. Nothing find helpful

Comment: @Amit Ramoliya : I removed all my echo . I don't required any echo. As I am using this as REST and throw JSON

Comment: @fresher click 6 and see the styles or which page it is in, by inspecting

Comment: @Farhana I post screen of inspect for welcome_message.php above

Comment: @fresher number 6 is print from controller. Check your code

Comment: @Abdulla Surprise part is, on local Machine I am not getting this problem. its only on Web hosting

Comment: there are some miss uploads. Upload the project again

Comment: @Abdulla To rule out this possibility, I downloaded entire project from hosting and configure in XAMP separately. But on local Mac there is no issue. Only difference is local is Windows mac and Hosting is Linux

Comment: @Abdulla - you are correct .. I am not able to find problem but after 4th attempt. it worked

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a strange problem like this, I type:

```
$ grep -rn 6 .
```

This will search the current directory for all occurrences of the mystery string.

Then it's usually a simple matter to find out where it's coming from.

Of course, you could also use xdebug to step through the program until it prints the mystery string.